# Can't add/remove items from a collection while foreach is iterating over it

Tags: c#, ienumerable

If I make my own implementation of `IEnumerator` interface, then I am able ( inside `foreach` statement )to add or remove items from a `albumsList` without generating an exception.But if `foreach` statement uses `IEnumerator` supplied by `albumsList`, then trying to add/delete ( inside the foreach )items from `albumsList` will result in exception:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] rockAlbums = { "rock", "roll", "rain dogs" };
        ArrayList albumsList = new ArrayList(rockAlbums);
        AlbumsCollection ac = new AlbumsCollection(albumsList);
        foreach (string item in ac)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            albumsList.Remove(item);  //works

        }

        foreach (string item in albumsList)
        {
            albumsList.Remove(item); //exception
        }



    }

    class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        ArrayList table;
        int _current = -1;

        public Object Current
        {
            get
            {
                return table[_current];
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_current + 1 < table.Count)
            {
                _current++;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _current = -1;
        }

        public MyEnumerator(ArrayList albums)
        {
            this.table = albums;
        }

    }

    class AlbumsCollection : IEnumerable
    {
        public ArrayList albums;

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new MyEnumerator(this.albums);
        }

        public AlbumsCollection(ArrayList albums)
        {
            this.albums = albums;
        }
    }

}
```

a) I assume code that throws  exception ( when using `IEnumerator` implementation `A` supplied by `albumsList` ) is located inside `A`?

b) If I want to be able to add/remove items from a collection ( while `foreach` is iterating over it), will I always need to provide my own implementation of `IEnumerator` interface, or can albumsList be set to allow adding/removing items?

thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally it's discouraged to design collection classes that allow you to modify the collection while enumerating, unless your intention is to design something thread-safe specifically so that this is possible (e.g., adding from one thread while enumerating from another).

The reasons are myriad. Here's one.

Your `MyEnumerator` class works by incrementing an internal counter. Its `Current` property exposes the value at the given index in an `ArrayList`. What this means is that enumerating over the collection and removing "each" item will actually not work as expected (i.e., it won't remove every item in the list).

Consider this possibility:

The code you posted will actually do this:

1. You start by incrementing your index to 0, which gives you a `Current` of "rock." You remove "rock."
2. Now the collection has `["roll", "rain dogs"]` and you increment your index to 1, **making `Current` equal to "rain dogs" (NOT "roll")**. Next, you remove "rain dogs."
3. Now the collection has `["roll"]`, and you increment your index to 2 (which is > `Count`); so your enumerator thinks it's finished.

There are other reasons this is a problematic implementation, though. For instance someone using your code might not understand how your enumerator works (nor *should* they -- the implementation should really not matter), and therefore not realize that the cost of calling `Remove` within a `foreach` block incurs the penalty of `IndexOf` -- i.e., a linear search -- on every iteration (see [the MSDN documentation on `ArrayList.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.remove.aspx) to verify this).

Basically, what I'm getting at is: you don't *want* to be able to remove items from within a `foreach` loop (again, unless you're designing something thread-safe... *maybe*).

OK, so what is the alternative? Here are a few points to get you started:

1. Don't design your collection to allow -- let alone *expect* -- modification within an enumeration. It leads to curious behavior such as the example I provided above.
2. Instead, if you want to provide bulk removal capabilities, consider methods such as `Clear` (to remove *all* items) or `RemoveAll` (to remove items matching a specified filter).
3. These bulk-removal methods can be implemented fairly easily. `ArrayList` already has a `Clear` method, as do most of the collection classes you might use in .NET. Otherwise, if your internal collection is indexed, a common method to remove multiple items is by enumerating from the top index using a `for` loop and calling `RemoveAt` on indices where removal is desired (notice this fixes two problems at once: by going backwards from the top, you ensure accessing each item in the collection; moreover, by using `RemoveAt` instead of `Remove`, you avoid the penalty of repeated linear searches).
4. As an added note, I would strongly encourage steering clear of non-generic collections such as `ArrayList` to begin with. Go with strongly typed, generic counterparts such as `List(Of Album)` instead (assuming you had an `Album` class -- otherwise, `List(Of String)` is still more typesafe than `ArrayList`).

Comment: Well said.  I'd give it +2 if I could.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - is it the enumerator provided by albumsList that actually detects ( and consequently throws an exception ) that we're trying to remove/add elements? Anyways, will follow your guidelines

Comment: @flockofcode: Yes and no. In reality, the way `ArrayList.GetEnunerator` works is by creating an object with a reference to the underlying `ArrayList` object, which maintains a number to represent its state. When `MoveNext` is called on the enumerator, it checks this number against what it was when the enumerator was constructed and throws an exception if the numbers don't match up. So it is an exchange between the `ArrayList` and the enumerator that results in the exception being thrown.

Comment: It's too bad Microsoft didn't define variations if IEnumerable, with different handling of the collection-modified scenario.  At least two I would have liked would have been IMultipassEnumerable, whose enumerator would include Reset and Count methods and guarantee that multiple passes would yield the same items, IModifiableEnumerable, which would allow modification during enumeration (though not necessarily thread-safe, and with no guarantee as to when modifications would be observed) without breaking the enumerator, and ThreadSafeModifiableEnumerator.

Answer (score 15):

Easiest way is to either reverse through the items like `for(int i = items.Count-1; i >=0; i--)`, or loop once, gather all the items to remove in a list, then loop through the items to remove, removing them from the original list.

Comment: Same reason I start from the rear when searching and modifying any type of text: the position of the "next" item doesn't change.  :)

Comment: Maybe, for(int i = items.Count - 1; ... should be better?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a collection, an array for that matter

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

I have a function

```
   public IList<int> myiterator()
        {
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(a[i]);
            }

              return lst;
        }
```

Now i call this function and iterate over and try to add

```
   var a = myiterator1();
    foreach (var a1 in a)
       {
         a.Add(29);
       }
```

Will cause a runtime exception

Here thing to notice is that if we are allowed to add for each element
in list

list will become something like `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`
then for every element and every newly added we keep on adding coz of that
we will be stuck in a infinite operation as it will again be repeated for every element

Answer (score -1):

From the MSDN documentation for [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx):

> You can enumerate over any collection
>   that implements the IEnumerable 
>   interface. However, to set up dynamic
>   bindings so that insertions or
>   deletions in the collection update the
>   UI automatically, the collection must
>   implement the INotifyCollectionChanged
>   interface. This interface exposes the
>   CollectionChanged  event that must be
>   raised whenever the underlying
>   collection changes.
>
> WPF provides the
>   ObservableCollection<(Of <(T>)>)
>   class, which is a built-in
>   implementation of a data collection
>   that exposes the
>   INotifyCollectionChanged interface.
>   For an example, see How to: Create and
>   Bind to an ObservableCollection.
>
> The individual data objects within the
>   collection must satisfy the
>   requirements described in the Binding
>   Sources Overview.
>
> Before implementing your own
>   collection, consider using
>   ObservableCollection<(Of <(T>)>) or
>   one of the existing collection
>   classes, such as List<(Of <(T>)>),
>   Collection<(Of <(T>)>), and
>   BindingList<(Of <(T>)>), among many
>   others.
>
> If you have an advanced scenario and
>   want to implement your own collection,
>   consider using IList, which provides a
>   non-generic collection of objects that
>   can be individually accessed by index
>   and provides the best performance.

Sounds to me that the problem is in the Collection itself, and not its Enumerator.

Comment: Does this have any relevance to the question?

Comment: Yes.  If the Collection that you're iterating over hasn't implemented INotifyCollectionChanged, then attempting to modify from within a foreach block will throw an exception.  This describes the cause of the problem, and points at how to solve it.

Comment: @W. Craig Trader: I think LukeH's question stems from the fact that there isn't any clear evidence the OP is asking about interaction with a UI. Furthermore, implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` does not magically allow you to add/remove from within a `foreach` block.

Comment: "Yes. If the Collection that you're iterating over hasn't implemented INotifyCollectionChanged, then attempting to modify from within a foreach block will throw an exception" But collection AlbumsCollection doesn't implement INotifyCollectionChanged, and yet foreach block doesn't throw an exception

Comment: "I think LukeH's question stems from the fact that there isn't any clear evidence the OP is asking about interaction with a UI." I've only recently started learning programming so I haven't yet covered any UI technology (such as Asp.Net)